# Apostrophe Validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm implementing a web application. Here, I'm struggling with a form validation. I just want to know how to allow the user to type letters, numbers and the apostrophe character in a text field using jQuery form validation method. Here with the question, I'm putting a sample code of the validation I have implemented.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("business_name", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9\']+$/i.test(jQuery.trim(value));
}, "");
```

Comment: It seems to me that my regular expression is wrong, because it gives me an error "Invalid characters" when submitting the form. So I just need to know what exactly I have to change /it in my above stated code part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple you need to pass

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9!\']+$
```

As regex, it will solve your problem